# Swift UIUserInterfaceIdiom error

Tags: swift, ios8

i use a view only in landscape for iphone 5/6/6 Plus / iPad Mini/iPad and now I would like to integrate the UIUserInterfaceIdiom in my application for use these devices in landscape.

```
func openGallary()
{
    picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
 {
        self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
    else
   {
        popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: picker!)
      popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
  }
}
```

I'm trying with this code but I get an error UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

Comment: UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

Answer (score 4):

You have to do it like this:

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {
    // .....    
}
```

you can also create a read-only computed property to return check it as follow:

```
var iPhone: Bool {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone
}
```

//

```
var iPad: Bool {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad
}
```

//

```
if iPhone {
        presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else if iPad {
       popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: picker!)
       popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
} else {
    println("Unspecified")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your orientation settings by clicking on the project file, selecting your target and inspecting the settings in the "General" tab under the heading "Devices". Make sure iPad is enabled.  The error also point to the user interface orientation (just below, labeled "Device Orientation"). Check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3** *version*:

//--- for **iPhone**: ---------

```
 if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone {
         // YOUR CODE
  }
```

//--- for **iPad**: ---------

```
   if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
       // YOUR CODE
     }
```

//--- for **Apple TV**: ---------

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.tv {
           // YOUR CODE
         }
```